# return string from one jsp to another

Tags: java, jsp

I have two jsp files. One is query.jsp and the other is b.jsp. b,jsp returns a string and query.jsp prints that string, but I can not print the string. What should I do?

Below is my code:

```
b.jsp

<%!
public String getName()
{
 return "Hello Martin";
}
```

and my query.jsp

```
<%@include file="b.jsp"%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1><% getName(); %></h1>
</body>
</html>
%>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible 2 solution

1. Use <%= %> instead of <% %>. Refer [JSP Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnaov.html) documentation.

   `<h1><%= getName() %></h1>`
2. Use out.println() inside <% %>

   `<h1><% out.println(getName()); %></h1>`

Comment: i first tried with `<h1><%= getName(); %></h1>` but it was not working.showing error `')' expected illegal start of expression`

Comment: Please remove semicolon`;`

Answer (score 0):

```
    <body>
        <h1><% getName(); %></h1>
    </body>
</html>
%>
```

should be:

```
    <body>
        <h1><%=getName()%></h1>
    </body>
</html>
```